# DAAB GetParameterValue does not return output parameter value

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, ado.net, enterprise-library

I have a stored procedure that recives as paramter as OUTPUT paramter. The store procedure sets its value. I have the following code in C# application. But I am not getting the value in application (the output is returned as zero). What is the missing link here?

```
CREATEPROCEDURE [dbo].aspInsertZipCode  
(  
   @CountOfUnchangedZipCode  AS INT=0 OUTPUT  
)  
AS  
BEGIN  
    SET NOCOUNT ON  
    SET @CountOfUnchangedZipCode = 13 
END
```

In the application, code is as follows

```
  DbCommand cmd = db.GetStoredProcCommand("aspInsertZipCode");
  cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
  db.AddOutParameter(cmd, "CountOfUnchangedZipCode", DbType.String, 1000);
```

The execution happens ...

```
  int TempUnchageZipCount = Convert.ToInt32(db.GetParameterValue(cmd, "@CountOfUnchangedZipCode"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to your SP:

```
RETURN @CountOfUnchangedZipCode
```

Otherwise you could use something like this after executing the command in your code:

```
var TempUnchageZipCount = (int) cmd.Parameters[0].Value;
```

Comment: Did this work for you? I tried this and it does not work. I posted a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39985999/microsoft-practices-enterpriselibrary-data-database-addout-parameter-not-getting