# Procedure output parameter always returning 0 in sql

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

```
this.status = Convert.ToInt32(((this.db.GetParameterValue(com, "Status") == DBNull.Value) ? 0 : this.db.GetParameterValue(com, "Status")));
```

The `Status` is an output parameter from the SQL Server stored procedure but it always returning 0.

Stored procedure is:

```
CREATE procedure CandidatesloginMaster_CheckSecurityCredential
    @CandidateID int output,
    @Username varchar(25),
    @Password varchar(25),
    @Key1 varchar(25),
    @key2 varchar(25),
    @Status int output
AS
    set NOCOUNT ON

    BEGIN 
    BEGIN TRY       
        IF(@Status = 0)
        BEGIN
            IF exists(
                    select Username,Key1,key2
                    from CandidatesloginMaster
                    where Username = @Username     AND
                          Key1 = @Key1 AND
                          Key2 = @key2
                 )
            BEGIN
                SET @Status = 1
                SET @CandidateID = (SELECT CandidateID 
                                    from CandidatesloginMaster
                                    where Username = @Username     AND
                                    Key1 = @Key1 AND
                                    Key2 = @key2)           
            END 
            ELSE 
            BEGIN
                SET @Status = 0
                SET @CandidateID = 0
            END 
        END
        ELSE IF(@Status = 1)
        BEGIN
            UPDATE CandidatesloginMaster
            SET Userpassword = @Password
            where CandidateID =@CandidateID AND
                  Key1 = @Key1 AND
                  Key2 = @Key2  
        END 
        print @Status
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
SELECT  ERROR_NUMBER() AS ERROR_NO,
        ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ERROR_MSG,
        ERROR_LINE() AS ERROR_LINE_NO
    END CATCH
END
```

I running procedure using directly in SQL Server then it print status values as 1:

```
EXEC CandidatesloginMaster_CheckSecurityCredential 
     1, 'User', 'pwd', 'User123', 'User123', 0
```

But with the same value through code behind it always returns 0 as status (output parameter).

Comment: what is your procedure? is the procedure giving rite value?

Comment: Yes, when I run procedure on sql server directly it works, but through code behind with same values this always returning 0.

Comment: Improve your question and provide sp code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6819535/daab-getparametervalue-does-not-return-output-parameter-value
will this help?

Comment: not works......! can help anyone..???

Comment: Is the statement I getting value in status in code behind is right?

Comment: Paste full code. How do you call procedure, open, close connection etc

Answer (score 1):

You defined the first and last parameters as `OUT` parameters. That means any value stored into those parameters within the procedure will propagate out to the *variables* in those positions when it is called.

The operative word here being "variables." It cannot change a constant.

Try this:

```
declare
   @CandID int,
   @Status int;
EXEC CandidatesloginMaster_CheckSecurityCredential 
   @CandID OUT, 'User', 'pwd', 'User123', 'User123', @Status OUT;
```

MSSQL, for what reason I simply cannot fathom, requires you to use the "out" designation not just when you define the procedure, but also when you *call* the procedure.